# Can someone please translate this art display?

Tags: translation

I found this at an antique shop and just love it. But I don't know what it means. Can someone please tray to translate it? Also is it worth any money... Thank You

[image: This is a 4 fold Art display]

Answer (score 1):

香風沐楊柳 - Refreshing wind bath the willow tree

白雲繞列山 - white cloud surrounding the mountains

飛雁送遠帆 - flying geese sent a sailboat off to afar

獨釣寒江雪 - Alone, fishing on the chilling river with a snowy view

All with the same date [癸丑](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%99%B8%E4%B8%91%E5%B9%B4/7907978)仲夏 (mid summer of most likely 1913年 or 1973年)

Comment: Just want to add that these expressed the 4 seasons in a year from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much is the price and how much you like the display.

It's closer to some kind of handicraft instead of art, so it probably doesn't have much of a resale value. However, if you really like the display and it's inexpensive, I don't see why not.